# I can not use django template-tag linebreak and justify

Tags: css, django, django-templates, justify, templatetags

I try to justify some text that i get from my database but I also need to use the template-tag linebreak.

html:

```
<p class="justify">{{ article.contenu|linebreaks }}</p>
```

css:

```
.justify
{
    text-align: justify!important;
}
```

My text won't justify itself unless I remove linebreak tag.

Got any idea how to use justify and linebreak tag together ?

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Django filter:

```
<p class="justify">{{ article.contenu|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```

I hope this help you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In template, you should use safe template-tag:

```
<p class="justify">{{ article.contenu|safe }}</p>
```

You can also use `safe` before `linebreaks` if you want:

```
<p class="justify">{{ article.contenu|safe|linebreaks }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but adding the tag `safe` does not help in my case. Auto escape is not off btw.